# Filter DescribeInstances with tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'm looking to see if it would be possible to filter the instances that my IAM users can see.

Example:
Clement will only be able to see instances that have the tag `AutoTag_Owner = Clement`

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc3jR.png)

Would it be possible to do that with a policy or something?

Comment: updated my policy to work on ec2 with all the resources associated with it but will only be seen when request has tags which has value Username= you-=iam-user, you can check